# How to fix VMWare Fusion Pro 10, "could not find any recovery partitions on this Mac"

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware-fusion

I recently upgraded to macOS High Sierra and VMWare Fusion Pro 10.

When I try to install macOS (as a VMWare guest) using the recovery partition option Fusion says:

> VMware Fusion could not find any recovery partitions on this Mac.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

If its any consolation I am seeing this with VMware Fusion Pro 8 also. Hat the latest MacBook Pro 15 inch 2016 model.

Strange how no one seems to no how to fix this issue. The only thing I can think of is that Run boot camp and somehow my portion map is different to what Fusion Pro 8 is expecting.

Will keep checking back on this three though!

Comment: Read over ["Why do I need 50 reputation to comment"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead) to ensure you understand how you can start commenting.

Comment: I gave up on creating a new partition from the recovery.  @SnapShot (https://superuser.com/questions/1256489/how-to-fix-vmware-fusion-pro-10-cannot-find-a-valid-peer-process-to-connect-to) Helped me solve part of my problems, and for creating a new OS X VM, I downloaded from the App Store and created a Bootable USB, then had VMWare Fusion reference it.

Answer (score 1):

I worked around this by downloading the High Sierra install app.
Then started the Create new VM Wizard.
Then on the screen where it gives options to select how to create, I dragged the installer app onto the wizard.  It created what i needed and the VM Booted to high sierra recovery.

Clicked installed new Mac OS X.

Boom.  installer

Comment: I was getting this error when trying to customize settings: "unable to create the installation medium"... but if you move the installer out of the Applications folder (where the AppStore puts it after download) then run the wizard again, BOOM! It works. No kidding.